# shell sftp download remote file

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

How to download the lastest file via sftp in command line?

This connects to the server and lists the current directory.. But how can I find the last file sorted by filename and download it?

```
sshpass -p $pass sftp root@$host << EOF
cd /var/www/bak/db
dir
quit
EOF
```

## update

```
#!/bin/sh

pass="pwd"
host="ftps://host:22"

mkdir /ftp
cd /ftp
curlftpfs $host /ftp -o user=root:$pass
ls
```

## error

```
Error connecting to ftp: gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that

Get latest file and save to `batchfile` file:

```
ssh user@server "find /path/to/dir -type f -printf 'get %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1" > batchfile
```

And get file:

```
sftp -b batchfile user@server:/
```

I checked and it works!

Answer (score 1):

It may be more convenient to use [`CurlFtpFS`](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) to mount `sftp` folder. Tutorial on ["using curlftpfs to mount a FTP folder"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mount_FTP#Using_curlftpfs_to_mount_a_FTP_folder) explains details.

And then use standard commands to achieve what you want to do.

Or for [`sshfs`](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) follow tutorial on [how to Mount a SFTP Folder (SSH + FTP)](http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-mount-a-sftp-folder-ssh-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux-using-sshfs-fuse/).

Not sure which `sftp` do you mean.